# Iteration among the tags inside an OSM - XML file

Tags: r, xml, openstreetmap

I am working on an osm data file like below.

```
  ...     
       ...   
           ...

   <node id="4165094897" lat="41.0492396" lon="29.0260049" version="1">
    <tag k="name" v="Adnan Yeri"/>
    <tag k="amenity" v="cafe"/>
    <tag k="wheelchair" v="limited"/>
</node>
<node id="4165094899" lat="41.0492902" lon="29.0258856" version="1">
    <tag k="name" v="Piano Restaurant Cafe"/>
    <tag k="wheelchair" v="limited"/>
</node>
<node id="4165094900" lat="41.0493468" lon="29.0258547" version="1">
    <tag k="name" v="28 Black"/>
    <tag k="shop" v="yes"/>
    <tag k="amenity" v="restaurant"/>
</node>
<node id="4165094901" lat="41.0494034" lon="29.0258145" version="1">
    <tag k="name" v="Gratis"/>
    <tag k="shop" v="yes"/>
     ...
          ...
               ...
```

I try to get the id, lat, lon ,amenity and name values of the nodes which have an **amenity** attribute inside the tags.

For instance, for the first node of the example data, since it has an amenity attribute inside the tags, I want to get;

```
         id        lat        lon       name     amenity
    4165094897 41.0492396 29.0260049 Adnan Yeri    cafe
```

However, since there is no amenity in the second node, I want to pass it.

To achieve that, I found the nodes including the aminity tag inside it by using `osmar` library as below;

```
require(XML)
data <- xmlParse("/users/maydin/Desktop/Istanbul.osm")

library(osmar)
datam<- as_osmar(data)

ids_a <- find(datam, node(tags(k== "amenity")))

length(ids_a)
15212 # Number of amenity in tags in nodes
```

After, that I used `XML` package,

```
for(i in 1:length(ids_a)) {

  find1 <- paste0('//*/node[@id=\"',ids_a[i],'\"]')
  find2 <- paste0('//*/node[@id=\"',ids_a[i],'\"]/tag[@k=\"name\"]')
  find3 <- paste0('//*/node[@id=\"',ids_a[i],'\"]/tag[@k=\"amenity\"]')

  on1 <- xmlAttrs(data[find1][[1]])
  on2 <- xmlAttrs(data[find2][[1]])
  on3 <- xmlAttrs(data[find3][[1]])
 ...
    .... }
```

After applying some dataframe operations, those calculations give the expected results. BUT it takes about 7.3 second for just one iteration. Since there exist **15212**, it means 31 hours!!

Then, I also tried;

```
xpathSApply(data,"//*/node[@id=\"6554996802\"]")
# 6554996802 is just one of the ids out of 15212
```

And it gave,

```
   [[1]]
  <node id="6554996802" lat="40.9220973" lon="29.1279101" version="1">
   <tag k="name" v="Burcu Cafe"/>
   <tag k="amenity" v="cafe"/>
  </node>
```

Since it makes just a single search inside the data, it is relatively faster. However, I couldn't make a step further from this point.

Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work pretty fast...
xpath to the rescue :)

```
library(xml2)
library(magrittr) #for pipe-operator

#read in xml (see section below for sample data)
doc <- read_xml( "./test.xml" )

#get the parent-node 'node' from a tag-node where the k-attribute = amenity
nodes <- xml_find_all( doc, "//tag[@k='amenity']/parent::node" )

#build data.frame
data.frame( id  =     xml_attr( nodes, "id" )  %>% as.numeric(),
            lat =     xml_attr( nodes, "lat" ) %>% as.numeric(),
            lon =     xml_attr( nodes, "lon" ) %>% as.numeric(),
            name =    xml_find_first( nodes, ".//tag[@k='name']") %>% xml_attr("v"),
            amenity = xml_find_first( nodes, ".//tag[@k='amenity']") %>% xml_attr("v"),
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE
          )

#           id      lat      lon       name    amenity
# 1 4165094897 41.04924 29.02600 Adnan Yeri       cafe
# 2 4165094900 41.04935 29.02585   28 Black restaurant
```

**sample data**

test.xml

```
<nodes>
    <node id="4165094897" lat="41.0492396" lon="29.0260049" version="1">
        <tag k="name" v="Adnan Yeri"/>
        <tag k="amenity" v="cafe"/>
        <tag k="wheelchair" v="limited"/>
    </node>
    <node id="4165094899" lat="41.0492902" lon="29.0258856" version="1">
        <tag k="name" v="Piano Restaurant Cafe"/>
        <tag k="wheelchair" v="limited"/>
    </node>
    <node id="4165094900" lat="41.0493468" lon="29.0258547" version="1">
        <tag k="name" v="28 Black"/>
        <tag k="shop" v="yes"/>
        <tag k="amenity" v="restaurant"/>
    </node>
</nodes>
```